# C# DataGridView- How enable vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

The DataGridView (Form) holds enough rows that the vertical Scrollbar is shown. But its not enabled. The Silder for Movement is missing and the Button Up and Button Down are greyed out.

=> there is a vertical scrollbar but not enabled.

I tried:

1. After filling the DataGridView the control is updated.
2. Resizing the entire Panel.
3. The Frozen attribute is false.
4. I a click in a cell i can use the up and down keys to scroll, but the scrollbar will not be enabled.

If I resize the Control while running (DataGridView is on a Splitpanel) the Scrollbar can be used e.g its now enabled.

Comment: Did you try this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.horizontalscrollbar.aspx

Comment: if you are talking about rows, and button up and down, then I think you may be looking for the VerticalScrollbar

Comment: refer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/9c9d2d67-c45f-4318-81ef-bf652358f582/

Comment: The problem is ->not<- the visibilty of the vertical scrollbar

Comment: You tried to set the width property to a smaller value?

Comment: Yes i have changed the width. No there is a 20 pixel cap between the datagridview and the splitcontainer. But still not enabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

**1.** One of your columns has probably frozen property set as `True`.

which should be `False` for all columns.

**2.**
Set the AutoSizeMode of the problematic column to AllCells

**3.** mygrid.DockStyle = DockStyle.Fill

Comment: I double checked, and no - none of my columnes have frozen set as true.

Comment: 2. | was: fill | is: AllCells | - and there it is , the sliders is enabled and can be used!  How and Why? But thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

1. You should dock fill your datagridview to panel
2. If you have some frozen rows, make sure these rows are set after you finish bringing data to your gridview

If you set the frozen row before, the row when added will take the default style of the first row, and all your gridview rows will have the option `row.frozen = true`. That's why the vertical scroll won't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Set ScrollBar property of datagridview is Both.

Comment: The DataGridView Class has no Propertie called AutoScroll (searched for this one too) See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Comment: earlier i was thinking that you are asking about Dot net bar datagridview control.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem plus some workarounds can be found here:
[DataGridView vertical scrollbar not updating properly (Forms bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632375/datagridview-vertical-scrollbar-not-updating-properly-forms-bug)
It definitely seems to be a winforms bug that appears, e.g. when a DGV is placed inside a tab of a tabcontrol.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the horizontal scroll bar.
Doing `PerformLayout` on the grid didn't solve it.
It turns out that the problem in my case was that the form was disabled.
We have an infrastructure that disables the form on load, loads a bunch of stuff asynchronously and at the end enables the form. 
For some reason this was enough for the scroll bar to stay disabled when the form was enabled (and like in your scenario resizing the form while running enabled the scroll bar).
So for me the solution was calling `PerformLayout` on the grid **after** enabling the form.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but this was frustrating me for weeks.

I have two DataGridViews on nested Panels.  The DataGridViews are Dock->Fill, the Panels on which they reside are Dock->Fill within additional nested panels.

The vertical scroll bars were highly unreliable when the form was resized - often the scroll bar might be visible but disabled, even though I could manually scroll down the grid using the down arrow in the rows.

The final solution was using "Tzachs" suggestion - after any resize event, invoke the "PerformLayout()" method on the grids.
This seems like a bug in the grid - failing to detect that the scroll bar is needed when the grid automatically resizes on a nested panel.

At least PerformLayout() solved my issues.